# How to call function inside jquery plugin after plugin is initialised

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I', creating my own jQuery plugin which can be assigned to more than one element in document. I want, on some events, to call a function inside plugin for that particular element, but everything is driving me crazy. Plugin, itself, works, but problem with external calling exists.

simple plugin:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            someOption: ""
        }, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            _init();
            _load();
        });
        function _init() {
            //some action..
        }
        function _load() {
            //some action..
        }
    };
    $.fn.myPlugin.reload = function () {
        _load(); //or this._load();
    }
}( jQuery ));
```

and in html:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<button id="button1">Click to reload</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var A=$("div1").myPlugin({
            someOption:"someValue"
        });
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            A.reload();
        });
    });
</script>
```

return is always that _load() is undefined... Any idea will be really appreciated.

Comment: Those functions are only available within the context that is created when `$.fn.myPlugin` is called. It cannot be accessed by `$.fn.myPlugin.reload`. You'll have to move said functions elsewhere where they can be accessed, or re-think how `$.fn.myPlugin.reload` is defined/used.

Comment: My suggestion would be to not use `$.fn.myPlugin.reload` and instead have your function accept an optional string parameter. If the first parameter is `'reload'`, run the `_load` method on the current collection, else do the normal stuffs.

Comment: @KevinB this sounds more like how jquery works

Comment: I agree to remove `$.fn.myPlugin.reload` ... But plugin is creating bunch of html elements to assigned div element when it is initialized. When I initialized again with a different parameter that is not the same object, and is not working.

Comment: Right... but the point would be if you pass in said string param instead of an object, init wouldn't run. only load. You of course need to also store the passed in options somewhere so said second run would still have them.

Comment: @KevinB can you tell me where to put that function to call _load function?

Comment: the majority of this is covered by the [jQuery plugin authoring documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/). The only thing it's missing is an example showing how to store passed in settings on the element for re-use, but that's made easy with `.data()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youre returning before you define the functions, also _load cannot be accessed from the reload function if its not in a higher scope:

```
(function ( $ ) {
//function definitions:
    function _init() {
        //some action..
    }
    function _load() {
        //some action..
    }


 $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
     var settings = $.extend({
        someOption: ""
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        _init();
        _load();
    });

};
$.fn.myPlugin.reload = function () {
    _load(); //
}
}( jQuery ));
```

Note that it can be accessed like this:

```
 $.myPlugin.reload();
```

Reload is not part of an myPlugin instance.

If you want to return a custom object for each instance do this:

```
 (function ( $ ) {
 $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
     var settings = $.extend({
        someOption: ""
    }, options);

     //function definitions:
    function _init() {
        //some action..
    }
    function _load() {
        //some action..
    }
    //iterate
    this.each(function () {
        _init();
        _load();
    });

   return {
     reload:_load,
   };
};
}( jQuery ));
```

Now you can do

```
$("test").myPlugin().reload();
```

Comment: tried.. not working.

if I call it like: `A.reload();` error is : A.reload() is not a function
if I call it like: `A.myPlugin.reload();` error is : Can't find variable _load

Comment: @ВојинПетровић it should with the last code ( ive edited inbetween). If not the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: well, those functions now are completely outside plugin, and they need to be in, cause they are using local plugin variables and elements.

Comment: @ВојинПетровић what do you mean? Do they need to refer to this?

Comment: well, I am creating lot of html elements within plugin and referencing to them in all functions inside plugin, including that _load function

Comment: @ВојинПетровић you either pass the data as variables or bind it to this. Theres no other way if you want it to be accessible from two different functions...

Comment: The location of the functions relative to the return statement isn't the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/yxLgumet/

Comment: What you are saying is to pass all data, settings, created html elements and all I need to use in any specific function? That would be really complicated and then it is not jquery plugin, just bunch of complicated functions...

Comment: I'm getting a little bit confused with all these answers. Is there any way, somewhere inside `$.fn.myPlugin` to have function reload() that can be called from outside event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144677/discussion-between---and-jonas-w).

Answer (score 0):

`A` is holding a reference to a jQuery object and as such has all the methods of `$.fn`.
But your `reload` is not a method of $.fn but of $.fn.myPlugin.
If you fix this and take Jonas` answer into account then it should work;)

Comment: yes, but I believe what user is saying is that `A.reload()` won't work because it's not a property/function of a jquery object, which is what `A` is.  So would need to be something like `$.fn.reload = `.. first *or* the `return this.each` should be just `return this`

Comment: I suspect there's more to it (the issue) though :)

Comment: As to my comment above, `return this;` in a plugin still returns a jquery object: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/